# Bind ComboBox To DataGridView Column

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, combobox

How can I bind `combobox1` to `dgv.Columns["cLoadName"]` ? so my Combobox always be above the column header text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "bind" you mean "show above the column" then use css to do that.
If "show same content" then you will need to bind your datasource twice - once to datagrid and once to combobox:

```
dgv.DataSource = ds;
dgv.DataBind();

combobox1.ValueMember = "cLoadName";
combobox1.DisplayMember = "cLoadName";
combobox1.DataSource = ds;
combobox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yes i mean "show above the column". Can you help me how to use css ?

Comment: You can look at an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EqdYR/17/
You need to make one <div> above your datagrid, put combobox inside it, using css make padding-left inside that div equal to all widths of your columns preceding cLoadName column.

Answer (score 3):

To bind data of your `combobox` to `ComboboxColumn` do this

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) DGV.Columns["yourColumn"]).DataSource = cb.Items;
//"yourColumn" is the comboBoxColumn in DGV
// cb is the ComboBox which contains Items
```